# iOS crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.6

I'm new to iOS, so don't be shy about pointing out any of my code that looks completely idiotic :)

Here goes...

Two view controllers - OrderViewController and LineItemViewController - when the user is on LineItemViewController, they can click a "Scan" button that sends a request to the server to mark this item as scanned.  That seems to work fine, but I get this error in the console app:

5/19/13 11:28:04.044 AM EvoScanner: tcp_connection_destination_fail net_helper_connect_fail failed

The app still runs fine after getting that error.  The issue is when I click "Back" to return to the OrderViewController, the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1).

I'm using XCode 4.6.2 with ARC enabled.

Here's my LineItemViewController:

```
// Interface
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LineItemModel.h"

@interface LineItemViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) LineItemModel* _line_item;
-(void)setDetailItem:(LineItemModel *) lineItem;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *scanButton;
- (IBAction)scanItem:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemLabel;
-(IBAction)scanItem;
@end

// Implementation
#import "LineItemViewController.h"
#import "LineItemModel.h"
#import "HUD.h"
#import "JSONModelLib.h"

@interface LineItemViewController () {
  LineItemModel *_line_item;
}
@end

@implementation LineItemViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.itemLabel.text = _line_item.product_title;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)setDetailItem:(id)lineItem {
  if(_line_item != lineItem) {
    _line_item = lineItem;

    [self configureView];
  }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self._line_item) {
       // self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}

- (IBAction)scanItem:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Scanning!");
    NSString *string_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:(NSString *)@"%@/%@",  @"http://localhost:3000/api/scan_item", _line_item.id ];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string_url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"status=%@",@1];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [messageBody length]];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[messageBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if(theConnection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");

        //receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"There was an error: ");
//        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"There was an issue sending the data. Please check your internet connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
//        [alert1 show];
    }
}
@end
```

And the OrderViewController:

```
// Interface
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "OrderModel.h"


@interface OrderViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) OrderModel* _order;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@end

// Implementation
#import "OrderViewController.h"
#import "OrderModel.h"
#import "LineItemModel.h"
#import "LineItemCell.h"
#import "HUD.h"
#import "JSONModelLib.h"
#import "LineItemViewController.h"


@interface OrderViewController () {
    OrderModel* _order;
    NSMutableArray* listOfItems;
}
@end



@implementation OrderViewController

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"View did appear");
    // show loader view
    //[HUD showUIBlockingIndicatorWithText:@"Fetching order"];

    //Initialize the array.
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *unPackedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *packedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSLog(@"ORDER: %@", _order);
    for(int i = 0; i < _order.line_items.count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"object in for loop: %@", _order.line_items[i]);
        LineItemModel *li = _order.line_items[i];
        if (li.qty_packed != li.quantity) {
            [unPackedArray addObject:(LineItemModel *)_order.line_items[i]];
        } else {
            [packedArray addObject:(LineItemModel *)_order.line_items[i]];
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"unpacked array: %@", unPackedArray);
    NSLog(@"packed array: %@", packedArray);

    NSDictionary *unPackedDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:unPackedArray forKey:@"LineItems"];


    NSDictionary *packedDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:packedArray forKey:@"LineItems"];

    [listOfItems addObject:unPackedDict];
    [listOfItems addObject:packedDict];


    // TODO: set the order id from the selected cell here
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    self.navigationItem.title = _order.customer_name;

}



- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    NSLog(@"MAKE DETAIL ITEM");
    if (_order != newDetailItem) {
        _order = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }

    // show loader view
    [HUD showUIBlockingIndicatorWithText:@"Fetching order"];


    NSString *order_id = _order.id;
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:(NSString *)@"%@/%@.%@",  @"http://localhost:3000/api/order", order_id, @"json" ];
    _order = [[OrderModel alloc] initFromURLWithString:url completion: ^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {

        // hide loader view
        [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];


}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (_order) {
       // self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"View DID LOAD");
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.  One for Packed items, one for items not packed.
    return [listOfItems count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"LineItems"];
    return [array count];
}


-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // NSLog(@"ORDER IN LINEITEM CELL: %@", _order);

    // NSLog(@"LINEITEM: %@", line_item);

    // New view code with subclass
    LineItemCell *cell = (LineItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LineItemCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[LineItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"LineItemCell"];
    }

    // Get the Line Item object for this row and section
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"LineItems"];
    LineItemModel* line_item = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.productLabel.text = line_item.product_title;
    cell.variantLabel.text = line_item.variant_title;

    int remaining = line_item.quantity - line_item.qty_packed;
    cell.remainingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", remaining];
    // NSLog(@"LINE ITEM CELL: %@", cell);
    return cell;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(section == 0)
        return @"Unpacked Items";
    else
        return @"Packed Items";
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"LineItems"];
    LineItemModel *li = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Line Item in final: %@", li);


    LineItemViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    [vc setDetailItem:li];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */

}



@end
```

UPDATE: After setting breakpoints for all exceptions, the trace leads me to:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "EvoAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Breakpoint leads to this line
        // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, ...)
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([EvoAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting breakpoints to see exactly where the EXC_BAD_ACCESS gets thrown?

Comment: How are the view controllers presented? In a navigation controller?

Comment: I'll give you +1 for doing a good job of describing your problem.  You need to set some breakpoints to trace down the cause of the exception, though, and also you should try to track down the cause of that error message, as it may be mucking things up.

Comment: @IkegawaTaro I haven't!  I tried logging a few things to the console, but that was a while ago and I forget the results.  Will comment again when I get more info - thanks!

Comment: @Wain Yes - the views are in a navigation controller.

Comment: Can you try to add a new exception breakpoint to be thrown on all exceptions, so that we can see on which line the app crashes?

Comment: @Chris - To do what the above commenter says: click on the breakpoint navigator in Xcode (on the left panel, second icon from the right).  Then click the + button at the bottom and add one for All Exceptions.

Comment: @IkegawaTaro set the breakpoint.  Line where the exception is thrown is in the updated question.  I'm still not sure what's going on, hopefully you can shed some light for me - thanks!

Comment: something is getting deallocated and then a request to access that is throwing the exception.  Can you confirm that `ViewDidAppear` is being called? And if so, does all code in the `ViewDidAppear` method of  OrderViewController execute before the exception?

Comment: @Chris, I have doubt on this line if you have `_line_item` allocated `self.itemLabel.text = _line_item.product_title;` in viewDidLoad of `LineItemViewController`. Have you checked this by putting a breakpoint ?

Comment: @IkegawaTaro no, ViewDidAppear is called when I first load OrderViewController.  But once I go to LineItemViewController and scan an item, then click the back button, the app crashes before ViewDidAppear is called again on OrderViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try unlinking the `delegate` and `datasource` links in IB and setting the `delegate` and `datasource` for the `UITableView` in `OrderViewController` programmatically

Comment: I *think* I've unlinked the delegate and datasource.  I did this by opening my storyboard file and going under "Reference Outlets" and deleting the two entries for datasource and delegate.  Not sure how to set them programatically, though, tried for about 15 minutes, and just not sure how to get it done.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: you could try setting them in viewWillAppear (you need to override this).  Set them by using tableview.datasource = self; tableview.delegate = self;

Comment: If that doesn't work google and search for how to use the built in zombie diagnostic tool.  It can be used to find the exact piece of deallocated memory.